# How do I upload a large file (~4mb) over https from winforms with a progress bar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, upload

Easy way how to upload a large file from winforms c# to asp.net https (web service or asp.net page), with progress bar?

Answer (score 3):

As you've probably found out, WebClient doesn't do a great job of uploading large files. I've got some source code on Codeplex that you can look at. The project is called [BizArk](http://bizark.codeplex.com/) and the class file is [WebHelper](http://bizark.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=bizark&changeSetId=42208#702750). It is based on HttpWebRequest and can be used to easily upload multiple files with progress as well as a number of other things.

Feel free to use the library as-is if you like, though it is mainly intended as reference code, not necessarily production code. I do use a version of this particular class in a production application but I don't remember if I've updated the source code with any bugs that I might have discovered after publishing it to Codeplex.

**NOTE:** The link is to a specific change set so if you are looking at this in the far future, you might want to make sure you are looking at the latest version.